Pakistani Passport with Valid U.S. Visa - Saudi VOA and E-Visa Concerns
I have a Pakistani passport and a valid U.S. visa, which I have used twice to enter the U.S. However, since the U.S. no longer stamps passports, I don’t have any physical entry stamps to prove that the visa has been used.
I’m planning to visit Saudi Arabia and understand that holders of a valid, used U.S. visa are eligible for a visa on arrival (VOA). Will the lack of a stamp cause any issues, or can I rely on digital proof (e.g., I-94 travel history)?
Additionally, I’m considering applying for a Saudi e-visa instead. However, I live in Jamaica, and the Saudi portal doesn’t provide an option to upload my Jamaican residence permit. Has anyone faced a similar situation, and how can I resolve this?
Finally, I have the following flight itinerary:

Return ticket booked through American Airlines from Kingston (KIN) to Miami (MIA).
Return ticket booked through Turkish Airlines from Miami (MIA) to Jeddah (JED).

The tickets were purchased separately. Could this cause any issues at immigration or with the airlines, especially regarding proof of onward travel or baggage transfer?
I’d appreciate any advice or experiences.

The separate booking is probably best asked as a separate question.  Assuming your valid US visa is a B visa then you should have no trouble with immigration or the airlines regarding your visa for the US.  As always with self transfers, you should consider what happens if your first flight is delayed or cancelled.  It's generally best to plan for a long layover to absorb delays.
